# Speeding up 3 body problem acceleration calculation

Tags: optimization, computational-physics, c++, eigen

I want to find optimizations to my code for the 3BP, and more specifically computing accelerations. I'm using a data-driven approach, so I have a `bodies` structure that contains arrays for mass, position, velocity, and acceleration, all stored as `Vector2d`'s of the library `Eigen`. So something like `array<Vector2d, 3> position`. (Mass is obviously a `double` array though).

What I have now is as follows:

```
void updateAccelerations() {
    
    //The rHat/r^2 part of the forces vectors, which is mutual between pairs of bodies
    Vector2d mutualVector;

    for (Vector2d &acc : bodies.accList)
        acc.setZero();
    
    //i, j just loop through unordered pairs of {0,1,2}
    int j;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        j = (i+1)%NUM;
        mutualVector = directedInverseSquare(i, j);
        bodies.accList[i] += bodies.massList[j] * G * mutualVector;
        bodies.accList[j] += - bodies.massList[i] * G * mutualVector;
    }
}

Vector2d directedInverseSquare(int i, int j) {

    Vector2d diff = bodies.posList[j] - bodies.posList[i];
    Vector2d rHat = diff.normalized();
    double rSquared = diff.squaredNorm();

    return rHat / rSquared;
};
```

Some things I've tried are pushing the `setZero` command to an existing loop in my code, and multiplying the `mutualVector` by `G` instead of multiplying two times when computing the accelerations. To my surprise, both changes slowed my code down by a slight margin.

An idea that I had, that is quite nice mathematically but probably not practical, is to recognize that:

$$G\cdot \begin{pmatrix} m_1 \\\ m_2 \\\ m_3 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} \vec{R}_{23} \\\ \vec{R}_{31} \\\ \vec{R}_{12} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \vec{a}_1 \\\ \vec{a}_2 \\\ \vec{a}_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Where $\vec{R}_{ij} = \frac{\hat{r}_{ij}}{\lVert\vec{r}_{ij}\rVert ^2}$

This is probably useless, especially since Eigen doesn't allow a cross product between a vector of doubles and of Vectors. I thought I'd mention it though.

If anyone can think of an improvement to the algorithm (or some optimization to the code implementation/other things), I'd be interested in hearing them.

---

Edit: Someone wanted me to post my `Bodies` struct:

```
using namespace Eigen;

#define NUM 3

typedef vector<tuple<double, Vector2d, Vector2d>> initialData;
typedef array<Vector2d, NUM> vData;
typedef array<double, NUM> Data;

struct Bodies {

    vData posList;
    vData velList;
    vData accList;
    Data massList;

    Bodies(initialData init) {

        if (init.size() != NUM)
            throw invalid_argument("Not Correct Body Amount");

        int i = 0;
        for (auto const& [mass, pos, vel] : init) {
            posList[i] = pos;
            velList[i] = vel;
            accList[i] = Vector2d(0,0);
            massList[i] = mass;
            i++;
        }

    };
    
    //functions for calculating energy conservation (irrelevant)
}
```

Keep in mind that **the initialization only happens once**, so I really don't care for its efficiency.

Comment: could you provide your bodies struct?

Comment: @MPIchael Added it as an edit

Comment: What integration method are you using? Boost::odeint, some other general library, or a home-cooked fixed-step method?

Comment: @LutzLehmann No library. I'm using the 4th order Forest-Ruth algorithm, which I've found conserves energy very well (makes sense, it's a symplectic integrator). I will also implement RK4 and RK-Nystrom in the future to see how they stack up in terms of speed and accuracy. All the above methods calculate acceleration 4 times a loop, so I'm pretty incentivized to make `updateAccelerations` faster.

Comment: With more than 2 bodies, there is no lower bound for the distance between the bodies. This means that one can get very high speeds with very small turning radii, requiring a very small step size, and no guarantee that it is small enough. As the symplectic methods only work as advertised for fixed step size, you will get also very many points on the boring slow, low curvature segments, which is wasteful. Methods with variable step size may not preserve energy, but give similar accuracy with less effort.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm making this simulation for a research paper, as a way to confirm some statistical predictions of the 3BP that a grad student in my department developed. As far as I know, the bodies should never get super close to eachother in the sorts of systems we're dealing with, so perhaps this isn't as big a deal as one would think. However, if this factor does turn out to make a difference, what methods would you recommend? Also, why is it that symplectic methods need a constant step size? I'd love to read about that.

Comment: @Remeraze - will you be running one simulation or maybe a lot of simulations?

Comment: @Richard for sure a lot, maybe millions.

Comment: @Remeraze - are you interested in squeezing perf here to fit this onto your available compute? A better ROI might be getting a supercomputer (often free for academic purposes and I can point you to some) or porting to a GPU. Both will increase your throughput, which I think is probably what you want. Feel free to email me if you'd like to discuss/collaborate.

Comment: The modified energy function is only valid for a constant step size, switching step sizes changes the modified energy that is almost constant. Coming too close to singularities of the Hamiltonian invalidates the mechanism that keeps the modified energy almost constant. So one can use step-size control with symplectic methods, but that removes all the advantages they have over other methods.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see. What if I use the energy and momentum conservations as constraints to the system and eliminate some variables, then use RK4 on the remaining variables? Then quantities will conserve nicely and I'd be able to use a varying `dt`. Also, what sorts of solvers that are friendly with a changing `dt` would you recommend for the 3BP, given that energy and momentum conservation are a very high priority?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is worth the effort, and if there is an easy mechanism to select the correct solution. But it should be possible. It might shift the unavoidable method error and concentrate it in some unexpected way. // There is an order-3 extension of the Heun method that makes for a very simple embedded 2(3) method. Otherwise use RKF4(5) or any other low-order Fehlberg method for a manual implementation and DOP853 or any other method of order 8 or higher if you use a solver library.

Comment: A nice introduction to variable step sizes is [this PDF by Feldman](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/math/vble.pdf). Fehlberg produced [a nice paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19690021375) where he compared easy and ad-hoc low-order embedded methods (with stepsize control) with FSAL variants with the same order and number of stages (virtually with one stage more because "first same as last (of the last step)")

Comment: I am certain, like others, that using adaptive time step size control is going to make your problem vastly faster because as long as body aren't close to each other, you can choose large time steps.

Comment: Adaptive time steppers are implemented in all of the major ODE solver packages, but are quite difficult to implement yourself. You'll be well served not rolling your own ODE integrator.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Scicomp!

For all following points, always *measure and compare*.

- Don't fall for premature optimization! It is the root of all evil. Is the time you spend on  optimizing your code worth your time compared to your other constraints (project time / available cpu resources / deadlines)? It is always possible to spend month of work to get your code to execute 10% faster...
- Have you turned on [compiler optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize%20Options)? (gcc yourprog.cc -O3 -ffastmath ...)
- It is possible your available hardware supplies optimizations which the compiler can use. provide the compiler with the information for which target you are compiling:  -march=native
- constify your code (tell the compiler all about which values are const after initialization, which arguments will not change during method invocation and which values are compile-time-constant (constexpr))
- try to add *inline* keywords to  functions as suggestions to the compiler
- can you eliminate the many multiplications of G? You could just multiply G at the very end, or combine it with the mass in a new constant outside of the loop.
- you might save time when squaring your norm (are you squaring two times, or are you calculating ^4 in one step and leave the details to the compiler)
- It might be possible to use [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) instructions of your cpu. Essentially you may execute arithmetic operations on small arrays of numbers in the same time it usually takes for one single value.
- If you are into that kind of thing, you can inspect and compare your bytecode in one of the available online compilers like: https://godbolt.org/ for the different variants you are trying.
- It might be worth a try to  unroll your for loop for the three bodies. That makes the code slightly less consise but more predictable (less jumps in reading memory into caches). You may do so manually, or tell the compiler to do it: for one loop: "**attribute**((optimize("unroll-loops")))"" or you can do it globally for your code: " -funroll-loops"

EDIT:

- If you want to run statistics on the trajectories of the three bodies, you can consider to simulate them *all at once*, i.e., increase the number of the TBP systems you solve significantly. If you propagate 10k of them in one run, you should be able to use all the cores of your cpu to their full potential and still wind up with the same statistical properties. (A more primite way to do that would be to start multiple processes.) I would presume your calculation is actually cpu bound and not memory bound. It should be possible to add another loop for the number of systems you want to simulate and surround it with a "*#pragma omp parallel for*". A neat advantage of that approach is that you can calculate and save your measurements as you go. That might sound like a small achievement but you can inspect and stop your simulation as soon as you see some error or abnormality in the results.(https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)
- This is a long shot but try if the compiler optimizations which aim to reduce the executable size help you ("-Os" iirc). The rationale is that you can sometimes reduce the instruction set to a size that fits into the instruction set cache of the cpu. It sounds counterintuitive but I had collegues who reported speedups better than (-O3), which tends to increase the size of the executable.

EDIT 2:

- Have you run your program with a sampling profiler yet? The idea is to run a long running simulation while sampling the code statistically as to which line or method it is currently invokating. Its a bit of tedious grunt work to get the profilers running, but once you have results you can directly inspect where the cpu is spending its time and any inefficiency will pop up at the top of the list. I used  [gprof](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gprof-2.9.1/html_mono/gprof.html) in the past with good results, but there might be more modern tools.

Also please share your resulting speedups:-)

Comment: I've indeed added `-O3 -march=native`, but `-ffast-math` both didn't give me big performance gains, and is less accurate than the default (accuracy is also very important here, including conservation of energy and such).
As for `const`, I read somewhere on SO that it doesn't matter for performance since there's a way to bypass it in code anyway (maybe the `mutable` keyword? can't remember). Is that false?
I've actually tried to combine G with mass, and it weirdly gave me worse preformence! but That was a while ago, maybe I'll try again.
As for the norm, I'm not sure what you mean. rephrase?

Comment: @Remeraze The `normalized` and `squaredNorm` functions both compute the square sum of `diff`. This duplication can be reduced by combining the operations to `diff/pow(diff.squaredNorm(),1.5)`

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see. I implemented what you suggested and compared to the old one (ran a loop of a billion calls to both functions), and It's about 25 times slower . I wonder what kind of magic optimizations Eigen does so that using it is so much faster than regular `pow`. Also, I just want to mention that you've previously helped me on another post on SO, and it was very helpful, so thank you.

Comment: @Remeraze : Speculation: It is possible that the compiler/optimizer inlines the code of the vector methods and recognizes the duplication of the square sum calculation, so that in the end `sqrt(r2)*r2` is computed, with only once computing the square sum `r2`. This in general will be faster than `pow(r2,1.5)`. In modern libraries, the power function `pow(x,y)` is a heavy overhead of special cases and argument reduction over the simple but at times insufficiently accurate `exp(y*log(x))`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I use `sqrt(rSquared)*rSquared` instead of `pow`, it's almost as fast (only about 10% slower) than Eigen.

Comment: Well, I tried `-Os`, and it was about 2x slower than `-O3`. Was worth a shot though.